# How can I return a boolean from a promise?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose custom service which will check if token exist from db and I wanted it to return boolean however in my controller I got a promise.

`token.services.js`

```
async tokenExists(token) {
 const foundToken = await TokenModel.findOne({'token': token})

 if (foundToken) {
   return true;
 }

  return false;
}
```

`Controller.js`

```
 const tokenExists= this.tokenService.tokenExists(token);

 console.log('tokenExists', tokenExists);
```

However I got a promise instead of boolean see below.
`Console Output`

```
 tokenExists Promise { <pending> }
```

Did I do something wrong? or is there a way for it to it?

Comment: `async tokenExits` <= `async` **makes** it return a Promise.

Comment: You better read about `async/await` and the logic behind.

Comment: Also small side note; `return !!foundToken` would return `true/false` without the if logic.

Comment: When you mark a function as `async` it wraps the entire function in a promise under the hood. You will need to await the function when you call it. For example: `const tokenExists = await this.tokenService.tokenExists(token);`

Comment: Thanks much, I got working..